# How to calculate step delay?

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper, calculation

I'm struggling with get suitable step delay while driving a stepper motor.

How to calculate exact step delay for 1.8deg/step stepper motor?
Give some example calculation.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. Please realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Convert the RPM of the motor to RPS.
- Take reciprocal to get seconds per revolution.
- Divide it by 360 to get seconds per degree.
- Multiply by 1.8 to get seconds per step.

Answer (score 2):

> How to calculate exact step delay for 1.8deg/step stepper motor?

each rpm = 360 degrees * rpm / 60 second.

So the time, between each step, is resolution / (60 * rpm), where resolution = 1.8deg/step in your case.